# Which ODE solver in Matlab allows me to advance in just one timestep only

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

```
[t,y] = odeXX(odefun,tspan,y0)
```

I have a solver odeXX, and the `tspan = [0 0.0001]`. It seems that for any ode solver in MATLAB, they integrate by breaking `tspan` into multiple steps (some adaptive like ode45 and some non-adaptive). But I am looking for the most primitive one--just integrate from `0` to `0.0001` in one step. Which ode solvers allow me to do this and how to specify this?

Comment: Most likely the solver will only take one step (using 5 function evaluations in the case of ode45). If it does not, then there is a  very good reason in the properties of the ODE. -- If you really want this, you have to program rk4 yourself, there should be some examples to be found here.

Comment: @LutzL There is a similar function in scipy that integrate one step at a time `ODE.integrate(..., step=1)` where ODE is imported from `scipy.integrate.ode`. how can I do this in MATLAB?